# REST API design - querying mail data - which poison to choose?

Tags: api, http, url, rest

we are currently designing an internal REST api. we have the following use case:

1. a user (109) wants to read a message that he has sent to another user (110)
2. the reading user (109) is known to the app through his token credentials that he received after authenticating (while doing the GET request)
3. we assume in this example the user 109 was the sender and 110 the receiver

to summarize from the users perspective "give me the mail that i (109) have sent to 110"

the following URIs came to our mind but we can't decide which one to take:

```
a) GET http://localhost:9099/api/mails/109?receiverUserId=110
b) GET http://localhost:9099/api/mails?senderUserId=109&receiverUserId=110
c) GET http://localhost:9099/api/mails?receiverUserId=110
d) GET http://localhost:9099/api/mails/me/to/110 (when logged in as 109 via token credentials we know that "me" is 109)
f) GET http://localhost:9099/api/mails/109/to/110 (explicit request, e.g. for admins … has to be guarded against illegal access)
```

all the links are "context sensitive" that is sending one of the links to the receiver (110) will yield different results executing the GET request.

i would like to know your opinion on what url to use.

any help highly appreciated.

cheers
marcel

Comment: Just an observation: (b) and (d) are identical.

Comment: I vote for c. I don't see the point in indicating the reading user, as it is known. (except for caching, though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different responses to different clients, for *same* URL is okay.

StackExchange does it:

```
GET /me/comments/{toid}
```

which is documented [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-comments-to).

Twitter does it too:

```
GET /statuses/home_timeline
```

which is documented [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/home_timeline).

Both of those URLs infer the logged in user based on authentication. Yes, it defeats caching if users share a cache, but IMO, this is okay. Whether or not this breaks the 'resource identification' constraint of REST is probably debatable. The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408191/is-the-twitter-api-really-restful) question, and a subsequent comment there shows to me why it is debatable.

In fact, among the options, you *do* mention URLs which are not 'context sensitive':

```
GET /api/mails?senderUserId=109&receiverUserId=110
```

This one will always return messages from 109 to 110. But while one client would want to see this result when viewing 'sent' messages, the other would want to see this result when viewing 'received' messages. Kind of weird eh? Plus, on the server you'll have to check that the authenticated user is 109|110, else throw a `401 UNAUTHORIZED`.

I would go with something like:

```
GET /mail/sent
```

returns all sent mail. And:

```
GET /mail/sent?to=110 (like applying a 'filter' to /mail/sent)
OR
GET /mail/sent/110 (clean URL)
```

returns mail sent to 110.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i think we will choose one of the links provied.

Answer (score 1):

"Context sensitive" links are bad idea for a *REST* API (in particular, this hinders caching). If you want to just use HTTP this is OK.

So I would suggest using URLs that do not depend on current user and limit access to them  according to your rules.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you need 2 layers:

One is the internal layer, which doesn't require user authentication, it's only accessible from internal components. It includes APIs like

`GET http://localhost:9099/api/mails?senderUserId=109&receiverUserId=110`

The advantage of this layer is the testability, reusability and cachability.

The other layer is the external layer, which requires user authentication and is accessible from external clients. It includes APIs like

`GET http://localhost:9099/api/mails?receiverUserId=110`.

Clients must login to get the token credentials, then server can get the user info from this token, and map the external API call to internal API call.

You may have different kinds of authentication methods, but the internal layer will not be changed, you just need to map different external layers to the internal layer.