# Angularjs convert service from $resource to $http

Tags: angularjs

How can I convert the following code service that uses $resource to use $http?

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('MyService', function ($resource) {
        var url = "..";
        return $resource("", {},
            {
                'servizio1': { method: "GET", url: basePath },
                'servizio2': { method: "POST", url: url, data: {} },
                'servizio3': { method: "POST", url: url, data: {} } 
            }
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have to do that? Using $resource is preferred to $http

Comment: In my Controller I call the service with the following code:     (new MyService()).$servizio1()
            .then(function (data) { 
            }, function (error) {
            })
            .finally(function () {
            });

Comment: @KhanhTO why Using $resource is preferred to $http?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17668516/3085821

Comment: @wickY26: using $resource conforms with RESTful design which has benefits http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191049/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-rest-instead-of-non-rest-http, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320003/why-we-should-use-rest . We only use $http when we have to work with legacy APIs not supporting REST

Answer (score 0):

First to your question, try something like:

```
angular.module('myApp')
   .factory('MyService', function ($http) {
       var url = "..";
       var basePath = "...";
       return {
               servizio1: function(){ return $http.get(basePath); },
               servizio2: function(data){ return $http.post(url, data); } 
           }
   });
```

Call it with:

```
var returnValue = (new MyService()).servizio1.then(function(data){...})
```

But actually you could also use the $resource API and do something like:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('MyService', function ($resource) {
    var url = "..";
    return $resource(url,{}, {
        saveIt: {
            method: 'POST',
            params: {url: basePath}
    }
});
```

adn call this with

```
MyService.get({}, function(data){...});
MyService.saveIt({}, postData, function(){success...}, function(){error...});
```

Check out [AngularJS docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource) for more